# commit changes from tag to trunk

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

On a subversion repo I accidentally worked on a tag instead of the trunk. I committed some changes since but they are not reflected back to trunk. How can I merge the tag back to trunk? Thanks, guys

```
trunk     tag
  |
rev53 -- rev53
           |
          ...
           |
 ??<--   rev62
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Any URL in svn-repo can be merged with any other. separation on tags (RO) and branches (RW) is just convention

**PS**: don't forget to kill bad tag after merge